# Retrive HttpStatusCode using webclient and then extract json In it. For use In C# client applications

Tags: c#, c, json, webclient, http-status-codes

For communicating between clients and server sides, I'm using webclient in my applications.
when a request returns 200 (means ok) I can use e.result, otherwise it would catch with an invalid data. but each server status code has a meaning [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx)  and sometimes it would contain some json data.

How can I handle server HttpStatusCode "except 200" ,and see data (json string) comes in that status using webclient?

postman simply show HttpStatusCode and also json data but how can I do it using webclient?

Comment: What does your code currently look like?

Comment: Just a comment...but why using `WebClient` when you can use `HttpClient`?

Comment: You need to handle `WebException` that contains `Respose` field.

Comment: @sajjad Are you calling this code from Xamarin.IOS or a ASP.NET or something else? Source platform may help finding solution. Also your current code will help a lot.